# Bash (or PowerShell script failing) - why?

Tags: bash, powershell, npm

I have a directory named `bin` that has a file called `build-code`, file type is displayed as "file".

When opened with notepad, the code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

rm -rf build
mkdir build

cp jspm_packages/system.src.js build/system.src.js
cp jspm_packages/system-polyfills.src.js build/system-polyfills.src.js

./bin/build-root
./bin/build-common-deps

./bin/build-home
./bin/build-navbar
./bin/build-angular1
./bin/build-react -p
./bin/build-angular2
./bin/build-vue
./bin/build-svelte
./bin/build-preact
./bin/build-vanillajs
```

When I try to run this file by navigating to `bin` and typing in `build-code`, I get the following error (PowerShell):

> '.\bin\build-code' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

And bash:

> $ build-code
>   bash: build-code: command not found

I have tried this in both PowerShell and GitBash. I have virtually no experience with writing scrupts for either (this is third-party code). What gives? Is this an invalid script, or am I doing something wrong?

As a side note, what is `set -e` doing? Seems to be setting some var, but I have no idea why.

P.S. npm tag is on the list, because this was initially being called from npm, but I am trying manually now.

Comment: If you're in the bin directory all the rest of the paths look rather suspect, unless you have another bin directory under bin. . . Is your script executable?  And `set -e` will cause the script to exit if any command exits with a code other than 0.  It's setting a bash option, not a variable

Comment: I will look into that, thanks.

Comment: try `./build-code` in bash

Comment: That's a bash script, so you probably need to invoke your build from bash (Cygwin?). Otherwise you need to rewrite them as batch scripts (with the extension .bat or .cmd).

Comment: @H_squared That worked. Also, Angsar - yea, had to run it in GitBash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing `./bin/...` to the absolute path?

Also, you mentioned navigating into bin before running the script, seems like the script expects to be run from the parent directory instead.

Comment: Would that really cause the error I am getting though? I am checking paths to other scripts as Eric suggested, but it seems like the 'build-code' script shouldn't be failing if it's valid.

Comment: even if you're inside the `bin` directory, you'll need to call it with ./build-code since it's not part of the `PATH` environment variable

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the sha-bang {#!/bin/bash} line at the very top. **(which you've done sort of)**
2. Using chmod u+x scriptname make the script executable. (did you do this?)
3. Place the script under /usr/local/bin folder.

After that, you should be able to run the script. This is typically what I do in CentOS / RHEL when needing to write and run a small script. What exactly is your script doing? building a folder structure? If so this too can be done pretty easily with PowerShell too.